# Setting testInstrumentationRunnerArgument from another task

Tags: android, testing, gradle

There is way to define which tests should be run with:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    testInstrumentationRunnerArgument("annotation", "com.hello.RunThisTestOnly")
  }
}
```

And another way to do it is with command line arguments:

```sh
./gradlew connectedDebugAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.annotation=com.hello.RunThisTestOnly
```

But when I'm trying to set the same argument from another task and run `connectedAndroidTest` the argument is ignored:

```
task taskX {
  doFirst {
    android.defaultConfig.testInstrumentationRunnerArgument 'annotation', 'com.hello.RunThisTestOnly'
  }
  finalizedBy 'connectedAndroidTest'
}
```

```sh
./gradlew taskX
```

Why argument is ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Android plugin configuration values can't be changed. More here: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/lifecycle-of-extension/36604/2?u=eugene

Comment: Is there any work around or proper solution you came up with?
The only way i can imagine is to create a cli script running gradlew with the parameters, but that sounds like extra steps..